# Obtaining Brazilian military service records?

Tags: military-records, brazil

Is it possible to obtain records of Brazilian military service from individuals who may have served in the early/mid 20th century? I have not seen any such records on familysearch.org or ancestry.com.

I am interested in determining an individual's service dates and whether they served only the required conscription or whether they volunteered for additional service beyond the minimum required.

I think what I am looking for is a "Certidão de Tempo de Serviço Militar".

Comment: This looks like what I want, but it's unclear how to do it from abroad, and it requires a lot of documentation: http://www.ssip1rm.eb.mil.br/comprovacao-da-condicao-de-ex-combatente/requerimento-da-certidao-de-tempo-de-servico-militar